# Exporting/importing data types in DBUnit?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, ibm-midrange, dbunit

I'm trying to use DBUnit to export data from our AS400 and import it into a HSQLDB database for JUnit testing, however, data type information doesn't seem to be exported/imported.  Everything seems to be exported (and hence would be imported) as CDATA.  Can someone tell me where to find the answer for this?

I've successfully built and run one of the examples:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    // database connection
    Class driverClass = Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver");
    Connection jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:as400://myserver;libraries=MYLIB", "user", "password");
    IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(jdbcConnection);

    // partial database export
    QueryDataSet partialDataSet = new QueryDataSet(connection);
    partialDataSet.addTable("TABLE1");
    partialDataSet.addTable("TABLE2");
    FlatXmlDataSet.write(partialDataSet, new FileOutputStream("flatpartial_as400.xml"));
    FlatDtdDataSet.write(connection.createDataSet(), new FileOutputStream("flatdtd_as400.dtd"));
    XmlDataSet.write(partialDataSet, new FileOutputStream("partial_as400.xml"));
```

This gives me, for example, the following output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
  <TABLE1/>
  <TABLE2 ADDRESS_ID="1" ADDRESS_TYPE="1" ADDRESS_DESCRIPTION="Billing Address          "/>
  <TABLE2 ADDRESS_ID="2" ADDRESS_TYPE="2" ADDRESS_DESCRIPTION="Delivery Address         "/>
  <TABLE2 ADDRESS_ID="3" ADDRESS_TYPE="3" ADDRESS_DESCRIPTION="Owner Address            "/>
  <TABLE2 ADDRESS_ID="4" ADDRESS_TYPE="4" ADDRESS_DESCRIPTION="Owner Previous Address   "/>
  <TABLE2 ADDRESS_ID="5" ADDRESS_TYPE="5" ADDRESS_DESCRIPTION="Store Address            "/>
</dataset>
```

Here is the DTD fragment that is produced:

```
<!ELEMENT TABLE2 EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST TABLE2
    ADDRESS_ID CDATA #REQUIRED
    ADDRESS_TYPE CDATA #REQUIRED
    ADDRES_DESCRIPTION CDATA #REQUIRED
>
```

The first field should be DECIMAL(10,0) but it's CDATA.   Obviously this would be a problem from a data integrity perspective.    In the debugger I can see that the type information is making it INTO the DBUnit package (the ADDRESS_ID field is DECIMAL inside the code.)   But that information is not making it into the XML DTD for the file.

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will help: 
Generete dtd file for tables you want to import

```
private static void generateDTD(String fileName,IDatabaseConnection connection,
        String[] tablesToExport) throws IOException, DataSetException,
        SQLException, FileNotFoundException {
    FlatDtdDataSet.write(connection.createDataSet(tablesToExport), new FileOutputStream(fileName));
}
```

then set this in builder

```
FlatXmlDataSetBuilder builder = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder();
        builder.setMetaDataSetFromDtd(new FileInputStream(schemaFile));
```

Comment: How do you user the builder to write anything?